# Class 'List<AnimeAll>' has no instance getter 'title'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building an app in flutter for watching anime using provider pattern.

However, I have a hard time working with it.

The error shows up in pages/tabs/search.dart

I can't access the "title" parameter fetching from provider.

I got this error:
[image]

## Code:

### main.dart

```dart
import 'package:anime_go/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:anime_go/providers/anime.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
        supportedLocales: [Locale('en', 'US')],
        path: 'lib/assets/translations',
        fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'US'),
        child: AnimeGo()),
  );
}

class AnimeGo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => AnimeModel()..addAnimeList(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
        supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
        locale: context.locale,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey[800],
        ),
        title: 'title'.tr(),
        home: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### services/anime_twist.dart

```dart
import 'package:anime_go/models/anime_all.dart';
import 'package:anime_go/.env.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class AnimeTwistApiService {
  static const baseUrl = 'https://twist.moe/api/anime';

  Future<List<AnimeAll>> getAllAnime() async {
    final http.Response response = await http
        .get(baseUrl, headers: {'x-access-token': EnvironmentVariables.token});

    return animeAllFromJson(response.body);
  }
}
```

### providers/anime.dart

```dart
import 'package:anime_go/models/anime_all.dart';
import 'package:anime_go/services/anime_twist.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimeModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  final AnimeTwistApiService api = AnimeTwistApiService();

  final List allAnimeList = [];

  void addAnimeList() async {
    final List<AnimeAll> animeList = await api.getAllAnime();

    allAnimeList.add(animeList);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

### pages/tabs/search.dart

```dart
import 'package:anime_go/providers/anime.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class SearchTab extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AnimeModel>(
      builder: (context, animeList, child) {
        print(animeList.allAnimeList.toString());
        return Column(
          children: [
            for (var anime in animeList.allAnimeList) Text(anime.title) // here is the problem - the error
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: add your AnimeAll model

Answer (score 0):

Your `allAnimeList` is a `List<List<AnimeAll>>`. So when you iterate over it in your `for` loop, one `anime` is now of type `List<AnimeAll>`. This type does indeed not have a `title` property.

I don't know what you *wanted*. Maybe you want to iterate over this list *again* and *then* use the title property of each `AnimeAll`?

To be honest it's quite confusing to me, you have a list of a list of something called an ...All (that to me would signal that this is a collection type as well), it seems you got confused yourself, maybe it's time to think about a better structure and naming of your data.

Comment: I remember answering the same question with this but he asked again, hmm.